# layout change on hover

Tags: html, css, webkit

Lately I've noticed a very weird thing in http://www.lua.org/docs.html – when I hover over the links beside the cover images, the layout changes!

I see this in Safari but not in Firefox. Some people have reported that it happens in Chrome too.

The page passes the validator at http://validator.w3.org/ .
The relevant CSS is at http://www.lua.org/lua.css.

It seems to be a Webkit bug. Has anyone seen that as well? Any suggested fix?

Comment: Whoa. Totally is a webkit bug. In Chrome, Inspect the element after the hover, and it will snap back into place.

Comment: It goes back if you hover over the images after hovering over the links. And then it never happens again for that link.

Comment: Here's the simplest test case I can come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/daQTK/1/

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It looks like this</strike>

`hspace="12"`

within each `img` tag might be causing it.

`<img src="images/pil2.jpg" alt="" title="buy from Amazon" border="1" align="left" hspace="12">`

When I remove it, the jumpiness goes away.

`hspace` is deprecated.  Perhaps webkit only partially supports?

You're right @lhf.

However, I think I found it now.  It's the `blockquote` that is surrounding the images and links.

When I remove it from the HTML, all fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it does not work for me. Note that it originally only happened once per link so perhaps you're seeing this. Try reloading the page.